# How do I give a value to a token with a contract already deployed?

Tags: ether, tokens, erc-20

I made a token which have no value.
https://etherscan.io/token/0xd911993ae8948d19eab8822305485f8b300a6dec?a=0xb133b946f8134a2c4abbf939fc6e1ac035c776e9

I want to buy them all at a minimum price, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot buy tokens with ethers from that contract because no functions is prepared to accept payments (the fallback function will generate an exception on every call).

Usually you have an associated contract called Crowdsale that will handle the purchase of tokens.

Since you are the owner you are assigned initially all to tokens and you can transfer tokens to other addresses.

**Note**: That contract was compiled with a very old version of the solidity compiler v0.3.5, I'd suggest to update immediately your compiler/wallet, last version is v0.4.17.

Comment: Thank you very much Ismael, you answered my question ...

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the right tick left to the answer, if it solved your problem :)